# PHP's execution time changes based upon internet/connection latency?

Tags: php, apache, networking

I'm hoping someone can help me understand something. If I'm accessing a website which is on the other side of the planet PHP reports ~300ms page execution time (via doing simple math with `microtime(true)`). If I access that same website locally on the server, PHP reports ~20ms page execution time. It seems like network latency is a factor in PHP's execution time, which is surprising to me because I thought the entire page was rendered by PHP and returned to apache to be immediately sent to client (thus, the script execution time would be the same, regardless of origin).

Apache, PHP5 (mod_php), CentOS 5.

Am I to assume that PHP is in some way waiting for output to be sent to the browser before continuing to execute? I have a feeling there might be some output buffering factors involved with this, but I really am not sure. I have output buffering turned on via php.ini.

My question is: what is going on, and how is my network latency affecting PHP's execution?

I hope this was the appropriate place to ask this kind of question. I tried searching SO & google, but had no luck with finding anything even relevant.

**Edit** I am not talking about measuring the time it takes for the webpage to transfer from server to client. I am straight up talking about how PHP calculates that it executes faster when I download the HTML source of the page from a local machine. Same server, same page, consistent results. I am using `curl http://example.com | grep milliseconds` in both locations to see what the server is reporting as PHP execution time.

Comment: Sorry but why do you think execution time is based on connection speed when you are executing it on different machines?

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit on how you're measuring these times?

Comment: @JeremyBanks I am measuring the execution time on the server side, basically `$start_time = microtime(true); $end_time = microtime(true); $execute_time = $end_time - $start_time`.

Comment: @AdrianCornish to clarify: I am executing `curl http://example.com | grep milliseconds` which shows in my terminal the HTML from the webpage. In the HTML of the webpage there's markup which indicates the execution time. So, in my example, I execute the same curl command, but on the server itself PHP reports a lower execution time. A.k.a. I am accessing the same website each time, not a different website. Same webserver. Just the origin of the connection is different and changes PHP's execution calculation.

Comment: @joneszach I am sorry again - why would you expect far away server to be quicker than a local lan server - what is your point?

Comment: @AdrianCornish should the server not /generate/ the same page at the same speed, regardless of connection origin? I don't see why it should take PHP 10 times longer to generate a page for a far-away user as opposed to a user on the same machine? I am not measuring the time it takes for the data to transfer from the server.

Comment: Because if you are using curl to time the result arriving at your machine then of course it will take longer

Comment: But I am not timing anything with curl at all. I am simply using curl to download a webpage's HTML. I am then looking inside the HTML of the webpage to see how long PHP reported it took to generate the page.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid yes, APC is being used.

Answer (score 0):

Two different machines, or even two exactly-the-same machines with different server software or different configurations can have drastic effects on your execution time. Anything may happen. A clog may occur (it has happened to me before), and suddenly the page takes 10 seconds to load. After that, you restart your browser, empty the cache, try again, and it is almost instantaneous again.

So after all that waffle, all I want to mention is, it has nothing to do with connection speed, or at least near nothing.

Comment: In my scenario, it's the same server. All I'm doing is accessing the webpage from different parts of the world, and when I'm closest to the machine, PHP reports it executes faster. I'm trying to ask why.

Comment: Where does the PHP reporting go? When it reports the execution time, another few milliseconds might have already gone past anyway.

Comment: even different access computers can have effects on the execution time on the server, as the browser wouldn't send the request across as efficiently.

Comment: I have PHP calculating time from the beginning of the script until the footer of the page where the execution time is calculated and echoed out to the page.